# ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a'

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

Anyone know what does that error mean? I have just copied my ASP classic website files to my Windows 7 x64 machine. And I have installed IIS 7.0. I am trying to access the website and it gives me that error.

Comment: You can download 64 bit drivers for Microsoft Access: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&amp;displaylang=en&displaylang=en

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [this thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1147654.aspx). There's no 64-bit Jet driver. You will need to enable 32-bit applications:

[image]